# Set ForeignKey in Django Error : matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

I want to set ForeignKeys to my tables in views.py but I got this Error

> Words matching query does not exist.

at this line of code :

```
  word_id = Words.objects.get(pk= wordID),
```

I don't know what's wrong and Why I got this error? So how I should set the foreign keys?

this is my model.py code

```
class Words(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phonetic= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    audio=  models.URLField(max_length = 200)

class Meanings(models.Model):
    word_id = models.ForeignKey(Words, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    partOfSpeech = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Definitions(models.Model):
    word_id = models.ForeignKey(Words, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Meaning_id = models.OneToOneField(Meanings, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    definition = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.definition
```

and this is the views.py :

```
def get_details(request):
    words = ['hello', 'table', 'windows']

    wordID = 0
    MeaningID = 0

    for word in words:
        wordID += 1
        print(word)
        url = 'https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/' + word
        response = requests.get(url)

        if type(response.json()) == list:
            response = response.json()[0]  # convert list to dictionary

        word = response.get('word', {})
        phonetics = response.get('phonetics', {})
        phonetic = phonetics[0]
        print(phonetic)

        word_data = Words(
            word=response.get('word', {}),
            phonetic=phonetic.get('text', {}),
            audio=phonetic.get('audio', {})
        )
        word_data.save()

        meanings = response.get('meanings', {})
        for i in range(len(meanings)):
            MeaningID += 1
            meaning_data = Meanings(
                word_id=Words.objects.get(pk=wordID),
                partOfSpeech=meanings[i].get('partOfSpeech', {})
            )
            meaning_data.save()

            definitions_data = Definitions(
                word_id=Words.objects.get(id=wordID),
                meaning_id=Meanings.objects.get(id=MeaningID),
                definition=meanings[i].get('definition', {})
            )
            definitions_data.save()
    return HttpResponse("data added")
```

Comment: There is no `Word` record in the database for the given `wordID`.

Comment: Did you check in the admin panel that the id you are looking for is present?

Comment: You can use **try/except** to avoid DoesNotExists Exception raised by ``get()`` method

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So I cant set All data in one method? I mean should I set words table data first and then meaning and then definitions?

Comment: Or you can use get_object_or_404: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django model instances primary keys do not reset to 1 after all instances are deleted and to reset the primary key I use this query on DB

```
ALTER SEQUENCE al_words_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

`al_words_id_seq` can replaced by `yourapp_table_id_seq` .